# Magento 2: Default REST API unable to update product data to multiple stores

Tags: magento2, rest-api, plugin

I've been having some issues with saving product data to multiple stores.

In any case...... to my plan of attack:

First I put in a before plugin to change the current store: (with hard coded store code/ids for testing purposes..)

it overrides the save() method in Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository:

```
class TestPlugin {

     private $_storeManager;

        public function __construct(\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager) {
            $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        }

        public function beforeSave($subject, \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface $product, $saveOptions = false) {

            $this->_storeManager->setCurrentStore('us_storeview');
            return [$product, $saveOptions];

        }



}
```

But this did not work - it only set additional attributes (and not the product name, price or any of the base attributes).  It also deallocated one of my websites i had assigned to my product.

I then tried to add $product->setStore() to the plugin - which worked:

```
class TestPlugin {

     private $_storeManager;

        public function __construct(\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager) {
            $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        }

        public function beforeSave($subject, \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface $product, $saveOptions = false) {

            $this->_storeManager->setCurrentStore('us_storeview');
            $product->setStore(1);
            return [$product, $saveOptions];

        }



}
```

My product is set to active on two websites - However - each time I run an update on a particular store, one of the websites is deactivated.

Is there any other way I can work with this existing code to set the context of the save, not the actual store allocated to the product??

I think it'd be a bit hacky to put another plugin in to assign it back to all websites after the method has run.

If this won't work - can someone point me in the direction of how products are saved on the admin side?  there doesn't seem to be any issues with that..  Or anything that will actually work properly...

Here is the original save method from Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository:

```
  public function save(\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface $product, $saveOptions = false)
    {

        if ($saveOptions) {
            $productOptions = $product->getProductOptions();
        }
        $isDeleteOptions = $product->getIsDeleteOptions();
        $tierPrices = $product->getData('tier_price');

        $productId = $this->resourceModel->getIdBySku($product->getSku());
        $ignoreLinksFlag = $product->getData('ignore_links_flag');
        $productDataArray = $this->extensibleDataObjectConverter
            ->toNestedArray($product, [], 'Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface');

        $productLinks = null;
        if (!$ignoreLinksFlag && $ignoreLinksFlag !== null) {
            $productLinks = $product->getProductLinks();
        }

        $productDataArray['store_id'] = (int)$this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();
        $product = $this->initializeProductData($productDataArray, empty($productId));

        if (isset($productDataArray['options'])) {
            if (!empty($productDataArray['options']) || $isDeleteOptions) {
                $this->processOptions($product, $productDataArray['options']);
                $product->setCanSaveCustomOptions(true);
            }
        }

        $this->processLinks($product, $productLinks);
        if (isset($productDataArray['media_gallery_entries'])) {
            $this->processMediaGallery($product, $productDataArray['media_gallery_entries']);
        }

        $validationResult = $this->resourceModel->validate($product);
        if (true !== $validationResult) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotSaveException(
                __('Invalid product data: %1', implode(',', $validationResult))
            );
        }
        try {
            if ($saveOptions) {
                $product->setProductOptions($productOptions);
                $product->setCanSaveCustomOptions(true);
            }
            if ($tierPrices !== null) {
                $product->setData('tier_price', $tierPrices);
            }
            $this->resourceModel->save($product);
        } catch (\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Exception $exception) {
            throw \Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException::invalidFieldValue(
                $exception->getAttributeCode(),
                $product->getData($exception->getAttributeCode()),
                $exception
            );
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotSaveException(__('Unable to save product'));
        }
        unset($this->instances[$product->getSku()]);
        unset($this->instancesById[$product->getId()]);
        return $this->get($product->getSku());
    }
```

**Edit:**  I've just found out I can achieve the exact same thing by specifying path as https://mymage.com/rest/{storeview}/V1/products/{sku} - however, it does exactly the same thing as my code - all other websites are disabled other than the one connected to the storeview in the URL.

***So the question now is - how to assign attributes to a particular store on a product without clearing the websites?***